# upgrade wizard "slugs" of TYPO3 9 failes with "something went wrong"

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

after upgradig an installation from TYPo3 6.2 to 9.5 (via 7 and 8) the last upgrade wizard "Introduce URL parts ("slugs") to all existing pages" crashes. There is no real error message, simply "Something went wrong" in an alert box.

All slug fields in the pages are empty.

Any ideas how to fix it - or to get a better error message?

Thanks!

Comment: might be the slug field is missing in the database, so execute the database analyzer before the last step.

Comment: Thanks David for this hint. But all required fields are present.

Comment: Use Ext. ig_slug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes there is broken Page Data. Did or do You have ext:workspaces activated some time ago? I would Check there for broken Datasets and delete them If not needed. If I remember right, i ran the Update Wizard through cli and got the uid of the First not working Page there.

Comment: I could not find the page which is broken. In the end i wrote some sql statements which imported the slugs from the old realurl data.

Comment: I marked this answer as solution because it would work if i could find the problematic page. in my case the best solution was to rebuild the slugs of the pages from realurl with some sql statements.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find the cause, you can also use extensions like 'ig_slug' to generate all slugs later.

Comment: Works perfect. I've made an upgrade from v8 to v11 and all slug fields were empty (FE 404 error). Install ext. ig_slug generate all slugs and everything works ...